# How do you change the elements in a div using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

have blade files in list format and blade files in image format. There are two span buttons here, and I want to show you a list of different formats when I click each button. How do I write the code?

```
 <span id="penpal-image-view" class="fa fa-th float-right" style="font- size: 25px;"></span> 
        <span id="penpal-list-view" class="fa fa-list float-right" style="font-size: 25px;padding-right:7px;"></span>
```

Currently, two blade files are only checked using the if statement, but I want to change that file when I press span

```
  @if( 2 == 2 )
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col"> 
                            @include('penpal.component.indexTableList')
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            @else
                @include('penpal.component.indexImageList')
            @endif
        @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose this is file1 and we getting an image from this file to file 2. This is a file containing image

```
echo "<img src="someimage.jpg" />";
```

This is file2 code
we get the image from file1 through AJAX like this:

```
$("#penpal-image-view").click( function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/file1",
    method: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $(".CLASS-OF-DIV").html(data);
    } 
});
```